# How can I submit a blank or "wild card" search query?

Tags: 7, search

I'm using the [Custom Search](http://drupal.org/project/custom_search) module to add some taxonomy fields to my site's search form, so I have a form that looks like this:

```
Business Name [text field]   
Categories    [select list]      
Towns         [select list]       
Price Range   [select list]
```

It works just fine, however, the search form won't submit unless something is filled in the original search text field. It would be quite useful to leave that blank and simply search for a category and town, or a town and price range.

Essentially I'm looking to add "OR" after the text portion of the query, or a value to insert, in case it's left blank, that will return all results.

Is there a file I can edit or a setting I can adjust to allow this?